# How to add an "alert" to this javascript button?

Tags: javascript, button, alert, clipboard

I'm not too familiar with Javascript and finally got this "copy to clipboard" button working with lots of trial and error, but I can't seem to get it to show a simple alert confirmation on click. I just need an alert that says "copied to clipboard!" on button click.

```
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> 
<center><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script><p id="p1">Text To Copy To Clipboard
Line 2 of text to copy</p><button onclick="copyToClipboard('#p1')">Click here to copy text</button>
  <style>
body {
              background-color:#999999;
              font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
      }
p
{
    display: inline-block;
  color:#000000;
  font-size:0px;
}
.textBox
{
  height:10px;
  width:10px;
}

button
{
height:10px;
  width:300px;
  border: white;
  border-radius:3px;
  padding:0px;
  font-size:18px;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  height:40px;
  cursor:pointer;
  background-color:#ededed !important;
}
</style>
<script>
function copyToClipboard(element) {
  var $temp = $("<textarea>");
  var brRegex = /<br\s*[\/]?>/gi;
  $("body").append($temp);
  $temp.val($(element).html().replace(brRegex, "\r\n")).select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  $temp.remove();
  alert("copied to clipboard!");
}
</script>
```

Comment: I don't see you even trying it.

Comment: You should check to see if your copy worked before alerting. Place the code that actually copies the text in a conditional, and place the alert in the conditional. `if(document.execCommand("copy")){ //then triggeralert }`

Comment: You really should show an attempt at solving your issue when posting on SO. This will help to ensure you do not get negative feedback from the community.

Comment: oops.. thought I included the version where I had it in the code. just added it back in

Answer (score 0):

**Do you want something like this ?**

```js
function copyToClipboardFunc() { 
  const copyText = document.getElementById("myInput"); 
        copyText.select(); 
        document.execCommand("copy"); 
        alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="Copy me!" id="myInput">

<button onclick="copyToClipboardFunc()">Copy to Clipboard</button>


<textarea cols=50 placeholder="Paste here to see clipboard data"></textarea>
```

Comment: this does work, but I need to hide the "input" (the text box) so it's hidden in the background, and I need to preserve line breaks within the copied output - which is the point of all the formatting and other code. but when I try adding just the "alert" function, it doesn't work

Comment: @MikeSheehan you just need to add some CSS, check this link. https://codepen.io/pen/gOgomqv

Comment: yeah I figured it out. it looks like I just had things in the wrong order. thank you

Answer (score -1):

Add a simple `alert("copied to clipboard!")` to the end of the click function:

```js
function copyToClipboard(element) {
  var $temp = $("<textarea>");
  var brRegex = /<br\s*[\/]?>/gi;
  $("body").append($temp);
  $temp.val($(element).html().replace(brRegex, "\r\n")).select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  $temp.remove();
  
  alert("copied to clipboard!");
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #999999;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}

p {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 0px;
}

.textBox {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
}

button {
  height: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  border: white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  height: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #ededed !important;
}
```

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<center>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <p id="p1">Text To Copy To Clipboard Line 2 of text to copy</p><button onclick="copyToClipboard('#p1')">Click here to copy text</button>
```

Comment: hmm. not working on my site for some reason. even tried copying and pasting your version exactly.

Comment: edit: got it working. I deleted all the other buttons, and changed the order of everything. put the javascript at the top, then the styling, and then the html. seems to work now. thank you